# I want to look at all of my notifications, but the Android App wants me to get a life

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, android-app

Whenever I pull down in the notifications area of the Android app, all the way to the bottom, and it hits the bottom of the area, it suddenly displays:

> No notifications.

This is horrible UX, don't you actually want me to look at my notifications and be active on SE, Android app?
Steps to reproduce:

1. Go into the notifications area
2. Hit the bottom of the notifications area
3. Displays No notifications message.

Seriously, can this be fixed? I'm using version 0.89. Screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This has been fixed in version 0.1.90 coming out in a couple hours.

I had a test that said "if the user finishes a pull to refresh fling and the list has more than 0 items in it, show the empty state" and that callback was also getting triggered when an overscroll happened from the bottom (since the library can support pulling to refresh from there too), but I didn't realize that I meant "and the list HAS 0 items in it" not "has more than".

Comment: Would you mind telling what caused the problem?

Comment: Me not knowing the difference between == and >, I edited some more info in :)

Comment: Free meta rep! :-)